# Styling parent if it contains child of specific class

Tags: html, css

I have html like this:

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second home">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to style div element with class *first* if child div has *home* class?

Comment: As of now No. It will be possible in css4... in future.

Comment: this feature is upcoming in CSS, See ref: http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

Can do it using jquery

```
$($('.home').parent('div')).addClass('first');
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('.home').parent('div').addClass('first');
```

All child element with home than

```
    $('.home').each(function(){
        $(this).parent('div').addClass('first');
    });
```

Comment: each loop is not required here...